# repeatedly poll database for pages, then output pages in sequence with slide effect

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I have a client who needs to output pages that are referenced by ID in a database. The pages must be output one after another (like a slide show), and there must be a slider transition effect. To make it "fun", the database will be changing as new pages are added, so a portion of the script to do all this must be run repeatedly to check the database.

I've got the pages to load, and I've got the transition working. The problem is, I can't get the polling to work because there's such a mess. That is, if I add a new page, I must manually reload the script - I need the script to detect new pages added to the database. I know that all I really need to do is just re-run the database query to generate the array, but with all the other stuff going on, I'm lost. I've tried setInterval() and even a while loop to no avail. At this point I'm sure I'm just missing something (hopefully) trivial, so I humbly ask for help. My code is VERY sloppy as I test, but here it is:

```
<?php
$community_id = 89;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// get all the pages that pertain to the community
$uid_query = "SELECT uid FROM pages WHERE pid=" . $community_id;

// build the javascript array by grabbing all results from above query
$result = mysqli_query($con,$uid_query);
$counter = 0;
$baseURL = "http://www.website.com/index.php?id=";

echo "var frames = new Array;";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "frames[" . $counter . "]='" . $baseURL . $row['uid'] . "';";
   $counter++;
   echo "frames[" . $counter . "] = 5;";
   $counter++;
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>

var i = 0, len = frames.length;
function ChangeSrc()
{
  if (i >= len) { i = 0; } // start over
  document.getElementById('frame').src = frames[i++];
  setTimeout('ChangeSrc()', (frames[i++]*1000));
}
window.onload = ChangeSrc;

</script>

<style type="text/css">
        body, html
        {
            margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
        }

        #iframe_container
        {
            position:absolute; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; top: 0px;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="iframe_container">
   <iframe src="" name="frame" id="frame" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

... and then any given page looks like this:

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hidden').slideDown(1000);
});
```

css:

```
.hidden{
   display:none;   
}
```

html:

```
<div class="hidden">
   CONTENT GOES HERE
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried making a separate PHP script to output data from the DB in a format like JSON and use AJAX to retrieve it on the main page? That way you could reload the content without refreshing the page.